# How do scrape the content from a collapsed box?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried scraping the content from the collapsed box halfway on this page. https://www.mijnautoonderdelen.nl/auto-onderdelen/vmf-54465-accu.htm

However when I parse the HTML it doesn't show the content I need.

[image]

But when I look at the real html I do find the required content.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can download the html from the collapsed box?